# Determine empty value on submit using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have this string

```
"fname=Nerison&mname=Sayson&lname=Pitogo&extname=&email=son2xp2go04221%40gmail.com&bday=1991-01-04&gender=MALE&address=Libertad%2C+Butuan+City"
```

Using regular expression, how can I determine that there is an empty value except for the extension name?

Comment: *"Determine empty value on submit"* are you trying to validate form data *before* you send it to the server (e.g. with JS)?

Comment: Can you please write what you have tried so far?

Comment: yes i am validating it using JavaScript b4 submitting. what im exactly looking is a regex that will match "=?" sign but should not include the "extname=&" because it can be emptied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this simple regex:

```
\b(?!extname)\w+=(?:&|$)
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yG3aM8), which matches two empty variables, but not `extname`

**Explain Regex**

```
\b                       # the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                         # something that is not a word char
(?!                      # look ahead to see if there is not:
  extname                #   'extname'
)                        # end of look-ahead
\w+                      # word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                         # more times (matching the most amount
                         # possible))
=                        # '='
(?:                      # group, but do not capture:
  &                      #   '&'
 |                       #  OR
  $                      #   before an optional \n, and the end of
                         #   the string
)                        # end of grouping
```

Comment: Almost working but it does not exclude the "?=" after the "extname".

Comment: @user2419435 Please see my update, which allows extname to be empty as requested.

Comment: @zx81 It works but not working while values has empty string..Check here http://rubular.com/r/UZPBSyP7bo

Comment: @VigneshKumar In your example `mname=  `has spaces, which (i) is not an empty string and (ii) is unlikely in a GET string. My [demo](http://regex101.com/#javascript) does get empty strings.